# Expected value and variance of $Z=-\ln(1-F(X))$

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance, cumulative-distribution-functions

The problem that I'm trying to solve is this:

> Continuous random variable X has $E(X)=a$ and $D(X)=b^2$ and cumulative distribution function (c.d.f.) $F(x)$. Find $E(Z)$ and $D(Z)$ where $Z=-\ln(1-F(X))$

I'm not sure how to start. I was thinking to find the c.d.f. of $Z$ and then the p.d.f., but the c.d.f. is something like this (if I'm not wrong): $F_Z(z)=P(-ln(1-F(X))\leq z)=P(1-F(X)\geq e^{-z})=P(F(X)\leq 1-e^{-z})$. And $1-e^{-z}$ is the c.d.f. of $\operatorname{Exp}(1)$ but I don't know if that is useful.

Comment: Your strategy correctly shows $Z$ has PDF $e^{-z}$ on $[0,\,\infty)$, whence any function $g$ satisfies $\int_0^\infty g(z)e^{-z}dz$. Can you evaluate this for $g(z)=z,\,g(z)=z^2$?

Comment: I think you mean $Z=-\ln(1 - F(X))$. There is a difference between $X$ and $x$. And you might know something about $F_X(X)$ when $X$ has a continuous CDF.

Comment: @Michael Yes, it should be $F(X)$, thank you, I'll edit it.

Comment: @J.G. for $g(z)=z$ I think it's $1$ and for $g(z)=z^2$ it's 2. From here I can find the variance.

Answer (score 1):

For any random variable $X$ which has an invertible distribution $F$, which is the case for continuous r.v., $U=F(X)$ is uniform on [0,1], always. Thus, the density of $U$ is $f_U(u) = 1_{(0,1)}(u)$ where $1_A$ is the indicator function over the set $A$. Thus, you can use this and the fact that $Z = Z(U)$ and $Z^2 = Z(U)^2$, paired with
$$
E[g(U)] = \int_\mathbb{R} g(u)f_U(u)du = \int_0^1 g(u) du
$$
to get the answers that you need. For instance,
$$
E[Z(u)] = \int_0^1 -\log(1-u)du
$$
which can be solved through integration by parts.